# How do I make Spring Cloud Gateway take my keystore as source of certificates to trust?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

After reading lines of [code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/ab3fcdfd5845ed85d21e6ffb09e6311092623b5f/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/config/GatewayAutoConfiguration.java#L714) for Spring Cloud Gateway, it doesn't appear to me that it actually uses the specified keystore as source of certificates to trust. Please forgive me if I am missing something important here.

The following is what I have configured to tell Spring Cloud Gateway where my keystore is.

```
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.ssl.key-store=mykeystore.pfx
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.ssl.key-store-password=password
```

Without specifying the keystore, no certificates are used as shown below.

[image]

Specifying a keystore, I could see the root CA certificates that came with JDK included as shown below.

[image]

My problem is none of my certificates in the provided keystore are registered or used after looking at each individual certificate shown in the screenshot above.

The screenshot below rules out the possibility that my keystore didn't get loaded. It shows that it is able to load my 3 private keys under the KeyManager. My keystore contains my private keys and certificates I need my app trusted.

[image]

This seems to me that it used the default keystore or truststore and combined it with my provided keystore but only to include my private keys and not the certificates in the provided keystore.

So my related questions are the following.

1. Is the configuration `spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.ssl.key-store` meant to specify a keystore that is meant to be **source of certificates to be trusted**?
2. How else can I tell Spring Cloud Gateway to use my keystore AND the default keystore (or truststore) that came with JDK **as sources of certificates to trust**?

Or alternatively

How do I provide my own implementation of TrustManager to the `HttpClient` that Spring Cloud Gateway uses internally for its routing? I've tried injecting that bean and called `secure()` to provide my own `SslContext` but that didn't work as it's not modifying the bean but duplicates it with the modification, it's immutable.

Comment: It is the keystone for the http client. Not the gateway server, that is standard spring boot.

Comment: @spencergibb, AFAIK the gateway uses Web Client or http client. The property being configured is named as `spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient`, doesn't that mean the http client of the gateway? I would be happy to be corrected.

Comment: @spencergibb, if that's not the way to configure the http client that the gateway uses, how do we configure its http client?

Comment: My comment says it is how we configure the http client, but not spring boot

Comment: @spencergibb, not sure if I'm getting you correctly. I'm not trying to configure Spring Boot, I'm trying to configure Spring Cloud Gateway's Web Client (or http client) such that it will use my given keystore when doing SSL handshake with the other services.

Comment: yes, that is what I'm saying that does

Comment: @spencergibb, thanks for even responding. Should I take your comment as there's currently no way to specify a keystore as source of certificates that gateway http client will use?